# apt-get update fails

Tags: debian, apt, update

I've got a problem with apt on my debian box. Since the beginning of July I've been unable to update packages, apparently because some key expired. I've found several websites that tried to help me, but none of the solutions provided worked. Therefore I am asking here.

When I run "apt-get update" I get this error:

```
# apt-get update
Get:1 ftp://85.17.159.15 etch Release.gpg [1032B]
Get:2 http://security.debian.org etch/updates Release.gpg [835B]                  
Hit ftp://85.17.159.15 etch Release                                               
Hit http://security.debian.org etch/updates Release
Err ftp://85.17.159.15 etch Release

Err http://security.debian.org etch/updates Release

[...]
Fetched 107kB in 0s (407kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: ftp://85.17.159.15 etch Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B
W: GPG error: http://security.debian.org etch/updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 9AA38DCD55BE302B
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I tried downloading and installing a new key but it did not solve the problem. Any clues?

Comment: Could you please post your source.list? Why are you using IP addresses directly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this :

```
gpg --keyserver pgpkeys.mit.edu --recv-key  9AA38DCD55BE302B
gpg -a --export 9AA38DCD55BE302B | sudo apt-key add -
```

That's a recent Debian system in order to avoid sources corruption

Comment: +1. You could also use 'apt-key add' to add new keys later.